# Java keeping pojo datastore independent

Tags: java, database, mongodb, cassandra, microservices

I have a microservice that currently uses cassandra for persistent.

```
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

 @PartitionKey
 @JsonProperty("personId")
 private UUID personId;

 @JsonProperty("personName")
 private String personName;
}
```

I would like to start using mongodb for persistent
and for that the class needs to look as below

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

 @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
 private ObjectId personId;

 @JsonProperty("personName")
 private String personName;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to keep pojo datastore independent therefore how should I create a pojo that would be generic and can work easily with both datastore?

Comment: I believe this may be able to help you: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations, you can choose the MixIn at runtime depending on your datastore.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this is with a single business domain and a repository domain. When storing, perform the conversion from a common business domain to a repository domain. Everything inside the application makes use of the business domain, so swapping data stores should be fairly trivial.

In addition, the use of a pseudo id can be used, so you can share a "primary" ID across database providers.

A library that can help facilitate this is [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).

Essential, something like this. A common business domain:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
  String id;
  ...
}
```

A Mongo implementation:

```
public class MongoPerson implements Mappable {

  @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId personId;

  // pseudo ID, generated and indexed. Optional
  String id;

  @Override
  ModelMapper fromMe() { 
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.createTypeMap(MongoPerson.class, Person.class);
    return mapper;  
  }
  @Override
  ModelMapper toMe() { 
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.createTypeMap(Person.class, MongoPerson.class);
    return mapper;  
  }  
  Class<?> getBusinessDomain() {
     return Person.class;
  } 
}
```

There's a bit more complication here if you want to keep this solution generic. Your service or DAO (Preferably the DAO, so you only need a single Service implementation) needs to have knowledge of the target type (e.g. `MongoPerson`, `CassandraPerson`). You'd need some sort of utility class to handle the conversion. Perhaps something like this:

```
class PersonService {
   // This DAO is just an interface that targets either MongoPerson or CassandraPerson, so the implementation may be swapped out.
   PersonDao<Mappable> repository;
   MappableHelper helper;
   Person save(Person person) { 
      Mappable mappable = repository.save(helper.convertToDomain(person, repository));
      return helper.convertFromDomain(mappable);
   }
}
```

In your `PersonRepository`, you'd have a generic method, `Class<?> getRepositoryDomain()` that would return the desired repository class, be it Mongo, Jpa, or Cassandra. Then, you can get the relevant mapper and convert:

```
Mappable persistenceDomain = personRepository.getRepositoryDomain().newInstance();
return persistenceDomain.toMe().map(person, persistenceDomain);
```

I've intentionally left out finer details, as it's quite a bit of boilerplate code, but this should get the idea across. Essentially, you do not use a single class for multiple databases, as that could get messy fast. Consider you may want to add SQL database support in the future, as well. I can't see those annotations playing nicely together.

Of course, this may also be overkill depending on your implementation, but it is an extensible, generic solution.

The whole point, however, is that you have a `Person` class that is a POJO. All operations are performed on this class. Then you convert that to entity classes that are database provider specific, and that is what is actually persisted. Those entity classes and daos or repositories have knowledge of the business domain (`Person`), but the business domain doesn't have knowledge of the repository domain.

Comment: We ended up with the same approach: there is _single persistence facade_ used in business logic, which depends on domain models only. Also, there are multiple maven modules providing storage-specific implementations. The reason of exposing exactly _facade_ is that some databases might not support direct 1:1 mapping of domain model to persistence entity. This is also the reason why ModelMapper might become a bottleneck. It is much more flexible to not constrain internal entities to single generic structure.

Comment: Any specific examples? The one I can think of that we will inevitably run into is NoSQL/SQL, as the way the data is stored is inherently different, but we'll be able to work around it. I also can't think of any spots where a 1-1 mapping won't work.